# How to retrieve data from zipcode and similar zip codes using MySQL query?

Tags: mysql

I have database which contains data for several postcodes. Some examples of postcodes are 2300, 2301, 2302, ..., 2340, 2341, ..., 2350, ..., 3000, 3001, ..., 9850.

I just want to show the data with postcodes related when someone searches with postcode as below:

Assume someone searches by postcode 2350, then the result will show all data for 2350, then it will show all data for 235X, then 23XX, then 2XXX, and then 3000.

Please help me how I develop a Query to retrieve the data as mentioned above?

Comment: Why 3000 at the last?

Answer (score 0):

if you have stored postcode as int you ca use between

```
SELECT * FROM postcode WHERE poscode BETWEEN 2300 AND 3000;
```

If its not Integer then you can cast it as unsigned

```
SELECT * FROM postcode WHERE CAST(poscode AS UNSIGNED) BETWEEN 2300 AND 3000;
```